# Expanding and Collapsing using selenium through crawling in java with [+] and [-]

Tags: html, selenium

I am trying to do expand and collapse with [+] and [-] in a website using selenium. My html code is

```html
<div onclick="abc_Click(this);" class="liCollapsed">
```

Here abc_Click(this) is the Onclick event which i am trying to click. The code I am using is

```js
   By.xpath("[@onclick='abc_Click(this)']")).click();
```

But the [+] is not clicked. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS

```
public void clickMenu(){
    driver.findElement(By.css("div.liCollapsed")).click();
}
```

A good approach with collapsible menus is to first check if the menue is already collapsed so:

```
    if(!driver.findElement(By.css("div.liCollapsed")).isDisplayed){
        clickMenu()
    }
```

Comment: I have two div's with same class name "liCollapsed", for two expandable icons. So how do i differentiate between two div's.If i use your code only the first [+] expands. please help.

Comment: should be: //div[@onclick='abc_Click(this)'], try that.